# Which Python files/folders are used for Linux distribution?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My C++ project needs Python to do some simple things (I/O, batch string find/replacement...). I want my program self-contained and do not rely on the environment of the target computer for Python.

I have included Windows Python distribution in my project. My C++ project will use this included version of Python (to execute attached small python programs/files) no matter there is another Python installation on the PC or not. So my program can run on any target PCs that may have a different version of Python installed or may have no Python installed at all.

My program can also run on Linux. Now, I need to do the same thing for Linux to include Linux Python in my C++ program. I have downloaded and built/made the Python 3.9.0 source tarball. But I don't know which files/folders are the distribution I should copy to my project. Or is there any ready-to-go compressed file I can download somewhere?

**EDIT:**

What I want is to include a Python environment (its interpreter and main modules/packages) in my program. When I call "python *aPythonFile*" from my C++, the Python interpreter used is the one included inside my C++ program's distribution. I don't want to use the unknown version of the Python interpreter installed with the Linux system. I don't want to pack my python scripts with the Python interpreter as well because I may add more scripts later on.

What I want is a kind of portable Python environment/installation (for Linux ONLY) that can be distributed with my C++ program. It will be used by my C++ program to run/excute my small python programs/files.

Comment: Have you tried [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/)?

Comment: Thank you @MattDMo. It is not exactly what I want. What I want is to include a Python environment (its interpreter and main modules) in my program. When I call "python aPythonFile" from my C++, the Python interpreter is the one inside my C++ program's distribution. I don't want to pack my python scripts with the Python interpreter because I may add more scripts later on.

Comment: Not sure the solution, but keep in mind that CPU architecture will matter, not just the OS